# How to pass parameter while redirecting to Action on Ajax Success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, popup, asp.net-ajax

I have two `View (Create and Completed)` and a `Controller`. I use `Ajax` for creating new records `(Create)` in a popup window and after the operation succeeded, I want to close the `Create` and display the returned message from the `Controller`. Although I can easily show the message on `Create` view, I cannot pass this message to `Completed` view (I want to close or hide `Create` and open `Completed` to show the message. So, could you clarify me please how to succeed this? On the other hand, is it not possible to determine if the request is an Ajax request with `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` method as shown below. Any idea?

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = null)] MyModel model)
{  
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //... (removed for brevity)
        TempData["message"] = "Operation succeeded.";
        var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Completed", "Home", new { /* params */ });
        return Json(new { success = true, message = TempData["message"], url = redirectUrl });
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Home")',
        data: formdata,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false, 
        success: function (response) {
           if (response.success) {
               //I can pass id in the url, but I need to pass response.message as parameter
               window.location.href = 'Url.Action("Completed", "Home", new { id=1 })';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

On the other hand, the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` in the Controller always returns true even if I make the request from another View (Create on a new page View) that is use `Html.BeginForm` instead of `Ajax post`. Is there a problem with `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` in MVC5?

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    //Always returns true
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What on earth is the point of using ajax when all your doing is redirecting. Do a standard submit!

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Do you mean using `Html.BeginForm`? If so, I need to use Ajax so that the model values would be retained on the popup window in case the request returns from Controller to the popup again.

Comment: But your not doing anything except redirecting - if `response.success` was `false` then the user is just stuck not knowing anything about what happened (or have you just omitted some code?)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Yes I removed some code for brevity. The only thing I need to solve is: **1)** I call the same `Action` in the `Controller` and I need if the request is coming from `Ajax Post` or `Html.BeginForm`. `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` **is not works and always returns true**. How to determine this? **2)** On `Ajax success`, I need to clear the current div and reopen another `View (partialview)` and display the message passed from the `Controller`. I make this by showing/displaying some `divs` on the same `View`, or opening another View by passing message parameter to it.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Any help please?

Comment: (1) `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` works fine (will only return true if the method was called using ajax) so not sure what the issue is in your case. (2) Your current code shows you redirect to `Completed()` which means you will need to add an additional parameter in that method if you want to pass a message to it. But is that really necessary. Surely if the user has been redirected to the `Complete` page, then it implies that _"Operation succeeded"_?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Of course I can show the same message "Operation succeeded", but I also need to show the specific id in it. On the other hand, why is it too hard or impossible to pass parameter in the redirect method on success? Is the idea not logical?

Comment: You can pass the parameter - your `Completed()` method just needs 2 parameters - `int ID` and `string Message` and you can do `window.location.href = 'Url.Action("Completed", "Home")' + '?id=' + yourID + '&message=' + response.message`. But if your passing the is to the method, why cant you just construct the message in the `Completed(int ID)` method since you know the ID?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Yes, you are right. Actually I do not pass ID and I just wanted to show that I can pass a parameter as ID :) On the other hand, the message may vary according to the different situation after the operation and for this reason I construct it on the Controller. So, if there is no better solution, I can pass the ID only and in case I need different message, I create another Completed view even if it does not seems good. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

In Success block of ajax before `window.location.href = 'Url.Action("Completed", "Home", new { id=1 })';` Use `alert(response);`

Remove unnecessary if block on success block